# How can I write regular expression for android:host

Tags: java, android, regex, xml, string

I have multiple hosts, for example:

- example1.myhost.abc
- example2.myhost.xyz
- example3.myhost.jkl

I want to write a regular expression for host name in the data attribute of intent filter. Which may look like this:

```
<data
android:host=".*myhost.*"
android:scheme="http"/>
```

But its not working for me. It seems that android:host does not support regex. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: can't u implement it within ur code? java sure allows regex

Comment: No I need to handle it only in intents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that android:host does not support regex.

Correct.

> Is there any way to achieve it?

You can say that you handle the `http` scheme and not specify anything else (e.g., no `host`, no `path`). This will cover all your desired patterns, but it will also cover every other domain name.

Or, since you can have more than one `<data>` element, you can have as many `host` attributes as needed to cover all of your sites, without regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am already having multiple <data> elements for different servers.

Answer (score -1):

If your formatting is consistent you could use [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-). It's faster than a regex anyway.

Given the literal string:

```
<data
android:host=".*myhost.*"
android:scheme="http"/>
```

You could capture "myhost" with: `string.split(".*")[1]`

Or you could capture ".*myhost.*" with: `string.split("\"")[1]`

Comment: @Downvoter Can I get some clarification on what's wrong with this answer?